# Multiple long pollings using php in news feed with likes and comments

Tags: php, long-polling

I'm developing a website where there are news items that are displayed in real time using the long polling php approach. Each news has like and comment buttons and the number of likes are displayed below them. So i managed to apply the long polling technique and the news are being generated in real time with the number of likes. The problem is, i also want the likes to be incremented in real time too. I was thinking of using multiple long pollings but i guess it uses so much server resource. What is the best way to do this??

Comment: You would want to implement some form of AJAX that is on a timer, polling every so often. It might be more effective to setup a cron task that polls the actual news sites, then caches them on your local server, and then have your AJAX poll your local server to serve the data faster. Of course, this assumes that your server would be a faster response. You could even translate the formats from the news sites into a lighter format like JSON, and strip out any unneeded data, so that when serving to your site, it would be much faster.

Comment: Im already fetching the news and it works great, but i want to keep the number of likes updated on the news items i.e. when a user likes any news post, the number of likes will be incremented directly on the other users in real time. I'm already using long polling to get the news, i just don't want to use another long polling for getting the likes

Comment: You should use long polling as a central information exchange system. It would connect to a PHP script that relays any and all information back to the browser, where it is then processed, and handled.